# Will my own items' active make my champion cancel my current spell?

Tags: league-of-legends

Say I go Katarina and I have Deathfire Grasp, then I go all in, and after I start the ult I try to activate the item. Will my character have to cancel the spell to use the item?

If I try to use it, will my ult be cancelled?

Are there exceptions with certain items/champions?

Comment: You should edit in summer spells too to make this compreshensive, it's a good question. 'What actions will stop a channeled spell?'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant exactly that. I edited entirely the question.

Comment: You always should try to start with the Deathfire Grasp before going in. So basically: Deathfire Grasp --> Q-->E-->W-->R...

Comment: Yes, I obviously should, but say I forget to use the item before the combo: when I'm already using ult I think "I don't want to screw it up" (because I'm not used to it, yet)...

Comment: Another situation would be when the target recalls without my range. sometimes I have to rush the approach using -flash E Q W ult-, leaving me no time to use DFG early. I mean, I can't imagine myself being able to move my fingers so quick, shift + 1/2/3 and the combo...

Answer (score 4):

I can only think of two item that have a cast time (Hydra/Tiamat) but for those that don't have one **you can safely use them while channeling**.

As long as an Item or Action doesn't force any movement, casting, crowd control or channeling you can use it while channeling without interrupting the spell.

As [Lolwiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Channel) states:

> Most activatable items and summoner spells can be used while
>   channeling without interrupting, which is particularly useful
>   information for jungle  Fiddlesticks: as consuming  Health Potions
>   will not interrupt  Drain.

Things that do interrupt channels are:

- Flash (Forces movement)
- Teleport (Forces channel + Movement)
- Hydra/Tiamat (Has its own cast time)
- Zhonyas (Forces self stun)

Also a thing why BotrK is pretty popular amongst ADCs like Vayne is the fact that its active doesn't interrupt your Autoattack sequence since it doesn't have a cast time.

You can also use Wards and Trinkets while channeling or being stealthed without breaking these two things.

Comment: Update: using deathfire grasp with katarina while ulting stops the chanelling. It's weird though